# Run Only Google Maps Android API v2 3

Tags: android, google-maps

I know this topics already have posted. But I am not success for this work.I can not run google map v2 in emulator. Now I am trying **BlueStack**. When I run BlueStack then it show **Get Google Play Service**. What I do please tell me.How I can run google map v2 successfully.

**My AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.gmapdemon"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

  <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="MY_KEYandroid"/>
        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"
            />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.gmapdemon.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an emulator from genymotion that supports google map api.  You can look this up.
Find a download for the app store that will run on your emulator. I found mine here: http://wiki.rootzwiki.com/Google_Apps#Universal_Packages_2... I was using the 4.2.2 version.
Drag and drop that into your emulator. I am using google nexus. 
Say ok to the prompts.
Once everything is installed close down the emulator and restart.
sign up with a good account.
Voilà

Comment: thank @Chole33 ..bro I want to do run Emulator or BlueStack..please help for this...

Comment: I am talking about an Emulator.   And I am not a bro.. ;).  Genymotion is a brand of emulator.  It is far quicker and easier to use than the one bundled with eclipse, for example.